# Private constructor or private function?

Tags: oop, constructor

I have a class with two constructors that share a bit of common functionality. They also have their own specific bit of functionality.

I was thinking of creating a private method and calling it from both constructors. Should this method be a private constructor?

Comment: I'm using Java but it was more of a hypothetical design question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this method is a common *constructor* behavior - then IMO - yes, it will make the code more readable.

A common usage is for example (java syntax):

```
MyClass() { 
   this(SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE); 
} 
MyClass(int x) { ... }
```

Sometimes you *have to* write this method as a constructor, if for example (again java) it sets a `final` field, which cannot be modified in a method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hadn't considered the problem with final fields.

Answer (score 0):

Both your constructors need a method, I guess before (or after) the have performed different operations. It does not have to be a constructor itself. It could, and in my opinion it should (at least as far as I can understand from your question), by a private method.